# Calling getInitialProps in children using NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am implementing data fetching in Next.js using this example:

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/examples/data-fetch/pages/index.js

I first tried it by adding the `getInitialProps` bit in one of my components but it does not get called unless I put it in one of the main pages.  I read some somewhat related discussions that I may need to call the children's `getInitialProps` from the pages/parent `getInitialProps` but not clear on how to do so. Also I am wondering if perhaps I should keep the call in the page itself as far as proper technique.

Answer (score 5):

Ah.. right from he NextJS docs :)

> Note: getInitialProps can not be used in children components. Only in pages.